$G_{\delta}$ sets in completely regular spaces
I want to show that the following are equivalent in a completely regular space $X$.

Every non-empty zero-set has non-empty interior.
Every non-empty $G_{\delta}$ has non-empty interior.
Every zero-set is a regular-closed set (i.e. the closure of the interior of the zero-set coincides).
If $G$ is $G_{\delta}$, then $Int_X(G)$ is dense in $G$.

The implications $(3)\implies (1)$ and $(4)\implies (2)$ follows easily.

How to show the rest of the implications?

For $(1)\implies (3)$ I need show that for any zero-set $Z$ (that is, $Z=Z(f)=\{x\in X\colon f(x)=0\}$ for some real-valued continuous function $f$), $\overline{Int_X(Z)}=Z$. If not, then there exists $x\in Z\setminus \overline{Int_X(Z)}$ and an open set $U$ of $X$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\cap \overline{Int_X(Z)}=\emptyset$. Since $X$ is completely regular, there exists a cozero-set (complement of a zero set) $X\setminus Z(g)$ in $X$, for some real-valued continuous function $g$ such that, $X\setminus Z(g)\subseteq U$.
I'm stuck here.

Could you add a bit more motivation for the question? Why would you expect these to be equivalent?

Spaces, which fulfill one of the above properties are called almost P-spaces, see here.
In fact, the above is literally proposition 1.1 from there. Therefore, I assume, you are aware of this paper.
However, the easy proof is omitted.
Therefore, here it is:
(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2): 
Let $G$ be non-empty $G_\delta$. Pick $x \in G$.
Since $X$ is completely regular, there exists a zero-set $Z$ such that $x \in Z \subset G$.
[Since countable intersections of zero-sets are zero-sets.]
Hence, $\emptyset \neq Int(Z) \subset G$.
(2) $\Rightarrow$ (4): 
Let $G$ be $G_\delta$-set of $X$, $x \in G$.
We have to show $x \in \overline{Int(G)}$:
For this, let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. Then $U \cap G$ is non-empty, $G_\delta$, hence
$\emptyset \neq Int(U \cap G) \subset U \cap Int(G)$
(4) $\Rightarrow$ (3): 
Let $Z$ be a zero-set in $X$. Then $Z$ is closed $G_\delta$, hence $Z \subset \overline{Int(Z)}$.
Hence $Z$ is regular closed.
(3) $\Rightarrow$ (1) is clear. 
Note, that we used $X$ completely regular only in
(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2).
